# ¿Como consigo que la función bool ejecute el caso else en c++?

Tags: c++

estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación. He empezado un reto que consiste en determinar a partir de una entrada si el número introducido es capicúa o no lo es.

Para esto he utilizado una función bool que retorne true si coinciden la primera cifra del numero con la ultima y en caso contrario que retorne false

El problema es que cuando llamo a la función desde el main siempre me ejecuta el caso de true independientemente de si la función bool ha retornado true o false.

Se que para ustedes esta duda será como sumar 2+2 pero yo estoy algo perdido y como les he dicho antes estoy empezando.

Les dejo el código por si tienen alguna propuesta de mejora

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


bool isPalindrome (int x ){
    int a,b;
    
        if (x<100){
        a = x % 10 ;            // Me proporciona la  primera cifra del numero
        b = x / 10 ;            // Me proporciona la segunda cifra del numero
        
          if (a = b){
            return true;
          }
         else {
            return false ;
         }
         
          
    
    
    }
          
}

int main (){
    
    int n;
    cout<<"Escribe el numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    
    if (isPalindrome(n)){
        cout<<n<<" is a palindrome";
        
    }
    else {
        cout<<n<<" is NOT a palindrome";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano. Y cualquier ayuda acerca de como seguir aprendiendo es bienvenida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (a = b){
```

El operador `=` es el operador de **asignación** y <strike>siempre retorna `true`</strike> siempre retorna el valor de la asignación, el operador que buscas es el de **igualdad** `==`.

UPDATE:

Como dice [Jose](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/116285/jose) me he confundido, el operador de asignación no devuelve siempre true, corrijo la respuesta para que sea de utilidad para futuros usuarios

Comentario de Jose:

> En realidad, FranAcuna, el operador de igualdad = no devuelve siempre
> true sino el resultado de la expresión. Por ejemplo if (a = 0)
> devuelve false.

También agrego información importante que menciona [CandidMoe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe):

> El operador de igualdad es "==". La parte '(a = 0)` es una asignación
> que retorna el valor cero. El if toma el valor cero como falso. Si
> preguntas if (a = 1) siempre sera verdadero para cualquier a. ¿Por
> qué? La expresión evalua a 1 y C++ considera verdadero cualquier cosa
> distinto de cero.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: En realidad, FranAcuna, el operador de igualdad = no devuelve siempre true sino el resultado de la expresión. Por ejemplo `if (a = 0)` devuelve false. No es por corregirte a ti sino para que no se líe nuestro amigo edu. Un saludo.

Comment: Entonces considera publicar la solución con la corrección que dices, así ayudarias mucho a futuros visitantes

Comment: El operador de igualdad es "==". La parte '(a = 0)` es una asignación que retorna el valor cero. El `if` toma el valor cero como falso. Si preguntas `if (a = 1)` siempre sera verdadero para cualquier `a`. ¿Por qué? La expresión evalua a 1 y C++ considera verdadero cualquier cosa distinto de cero.

Comment: yo la verdad es que me he perdido un poco con esta nueva explicación jajajajaj. Si el operador = es de asignación , entonce la expresión a=0 asigna a "a" el valor 0 no ? por eso siempre es true no? porque no hay realmente ninguna condición a evaluar sino que siempre se va a cumplir la orden de asignar a=0. Esto fue lo que yo entendi , estoy equivocado ??

Comment: De todas formas muchisimas gracias a todos por el apoyo y por tratar de ayudar a alguien que esta empezando. Gracias de verdad

Answer (score 1):

Os dejo el código aqui por si alguien quiere echarle un vistazo al problema de los numeros capicuas.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


bool isPalindrome (int x ){
    int a,b;
    int d,e,f,g;
    
    if (x<100){
        a = x % 10 ;            // Me proporciona la  primera cifra del numero
        b = x / 10 ;            // Me proporciona la segunda cifra del numero
        
          if (a == b){
            return true;
          }
            return false;
          
    
    }
    if (x>100 , x<1000){
            
            
        a = x % 10 ;            // Me proporciona la  primera cifra del numero
        b = x / 100 ;            // Me proporciona la segunda cifra del numero
        
          if (a == b){
            return true;
          }
            return false;
        
    }
    if (x>1000 , x<10000){
        
        a = x % 10 ;            // Me proporciona la  primera cifra del numero
        b = x / 1000 ;         // Me proporciona la segunda cifra del numero
        d = x % 1000 ;        //Me proporciona el numero sin la primera cifra   
        e= x % 100 ;          // Me proporciona los dos ultimos numeros 
        f = d/100;            // Me proporciona el primer numero de d
        g=  e/10;              //Me proporciona el primer numero de e
        
        
          if (a == b, f == g){
            return true;
          }
            return false;
        
    }
    
        if (x>10000 , x<100000){
        
        a = x % 10 ;            // Me proporciona la  primera cifra del numero
        b = x / 10000 ;            // Me proporciona la segunda cifra del numero
        d = x % 10000 ;
        e= x % 100 ;
        f = d/1000;
        g=  e/10;
        
        
          if (a == b, f == g){
            return true;
          }
            return false;
        
    }
    
    
}

int main (){
    
    int n;
    cout<<"Escribe el numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    
    if (isPalindrome(n)){
        cout<<n<<" is a palindrome";
        
    }
    else {
        cout<<n<<" is NOT a palindrome";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta o parte de la pregunta?

Comment: @BetaM Este es el código que yo cree para comprobar si un numero es capicúa (palindrome en ingles) . El código funciona para una entrada menor de 1000000. Aun así si alguien tiene un método más elegante o simplemente otra forma de plantear el problema es siempre bien venido otro punto de vista que no sea el propio para ver otras formas de solucionar el problema.

Comment: Entiendo, considera editar y explicarlo mas a detalle así le será mucho mas de utilidad a otros usuarios que lo consulten

Comment: @BetaM Te refieres a añadir mas comentarios al código ? o a poner una descripción exhaustiva antes del código ? Gracias por ayudarme a mejorar!

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy buena, igual solo ampliar la explicación un poco mas la haría aún mas genial ;)

Comment: Y si buscas una solución más *elegante* (al menos seguro que más corta, y te apetece un reto), prueba a convertir el número a string y recorrerlo por ambos extremos a la vez. Si lo planteas bien tan solo necesitas un bucle con tres líneas de código!

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por el reto!! Intentare hacerlo como tu dices y si lo consigo lo publicare también en este hilo para ayudar a quien le interese.